# How can an app show YouTube videos and still meet Google's app guidelines?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, android-videoview

Which is the way to display YouTube videos of a website in my Android app (not open YouTube app)? Note that I've seen it in other apps.

I am using a webView of my website (where you can play YouTube videos, and it's responsive for mobile devices) in my android app. I don't have any ads in my Android app (neither in my web). When I tried to upload my app I received a message (see below) telling me that I should make sure of not show or download videos of YouTube, but I've seen other Android apps (like "ELLE" app) which does it, you can display YouTube videos from the Android app.

Here it comes what I received:

> I reviewed your application and had to reject it because it violates
>   our device and network abuse policy and section 4.4 of the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement. If you submitted an update, the previous
>   version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>
> Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> - Modify your app to make sure it doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, by
>     enabling background play of YouTube videos.
> - Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details and examples.
> - Make sure your app is compliant with all other policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement
>     could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Seems to be a "legal" question about Google's policies rather than about programming per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an intent to open the video in a youtube app if it is present on the device or open it in the default browser. Now how do you get an event in the app if the youtube link is present on your website - This can be done by using javascript - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html

Comment: Thanks! I saw that the event for going back is: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;

Which one would be for playing a YouTube video of my web site? Or how can I know that the user is playing the video to fire that intent? I'm confused at that point

Comment: You have to write a small javascript code on your wesbite to let the app know when user presses on that link - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html#calling-from-javascript-to-the-android-web-app